# Multiplication with functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop, multiplication

I am new to functions and i am really trying to understand how they work, my teacher gave us a problem where by we were to pass a number to a function between the range of 1-12 and the function was then meant to do the times tales of that number so I asked the user to enter a number and if the number is less then 1 and greater then 12 exit, else pass the number to the function and then I used a for loop to do the multiplication for me (as far as I am aware) but nothing seems to happen? Νo doubt I am doing something really stupid, any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int TimesTables (int num);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int number;
    cout << "enter a number to multiply by, with a range of 1-12: ";
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 1 && number > 12)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    else {
        int tables = TimesTables(number);
        cout << tables;
    }
    return 0;
}
int TimesTables (int num) {

    for ( int i = 0; num <=12; i ++)
        num = num * i;
    return num;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ( int i = 0; num <=12; i ++)
    num = num * i;
```

Here `i` starts from 0, so any multiplication you do afterwards doesn't affect the result (`num`). Moreover, you want to go from 1 to 12, so you should start from 0 and finish at 12 - 1, or start from 1 and finish at 12.

So change this:

```
for ( int i = 0; num <=12; i ++)
```

to this:

```
for ( int i = 1; i <=12; i ++)
```

since you want to stop when `i` reaches 12, not `num`, `i` is the counter of the [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop)!

Comment: You are welcome @Dean. And BTW there is no silly mistake, you are learning, so it was good to ask-that's why I upvoted you, because I saw some effort there! I also updated my answer with a simple, beginner's debugging technique which can help you next time! PS -  don't forget to *accept* an answer.

Comment: This code doesn't work, gsamaras. However, you could have seen that by yourself, if you you had run this.

Comment: You may want to also check i in the for loop. You would have seen the problem if you had run this (or read the other answer). It happens to all of us.

Comment: I have upvoted the other answer, but yes, I missed that @KennyOstrom, I am sorry! Good think you insisted, do you like now my answer? :D

Answer (score 4):

Running `i` from 0 is going to set `num` to 0, and therefore any multiplication after that.

Your loop is also rather dubious. Why are you checking `num <= 12` rather than `i <= 12`?

Shouldn't your loop take the form

```
for ( int i = 1; i <=12; i ++){
    // Print num * i
    cout << num * i;
}
// There's no need to return anything back to the caller
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really silly mistake on my part, but if i don't return anything then i get the error "control reaches en of non void function" i thought i would need a return? especially because i am trying to return num back to main and output the result

Comment: I think it will be good to return `num`, since it's something their teacher instructed them to do, so it has to do with the flow of the course. BTW, it seems that your answer came a bit earlier's than mine, so I updated mine's a bit, to make it a little different than yours. +1.

Comment: also now that i execute the program it just returns me an error and shows me all the pointer locations? ill mess around with it some more and try to fix it, thanks again for your help guys, much appreciated!

Comment: Why would you return a single number for a times table? The OP does not mention returning a number. I think this answer is intended to go with this function prototype:  void PrintTimesTable(int num);